# Opening context menu on a browser on Linux using JS

Tags: javascript, linux, events, menu, webapi

I am working on an browser extension and I have encounter an issue on Linux.

Unlike windows, where the context menu appears after right button **release**, on Linux the context menu appears after right button **press**.

I am trying to force the context menu to work like it would on windows.
I manage to prevent the context menu to appear after mouse press, but I don't know how to cause the context menu to appear after mouse release.

Comment: Show some code, between linux, windows, mobile they all utilize a different form of click. Mostly pointerdown type stuff is supported across all devices (touch included) and you can determine then. If a device is unable to support right click you need to determine ahead of time if you want to use that feature!

Comment: I'd say due to how browsers work and all sorts, you don't want to modify right-clicking unless blocking it completely cause of the behavior differences amongst browsers/devices. In my case for browsers that do support it and the app is graphical, I treat both as a singular click like mobile to keep 100% presence any device.